# Handling exports that takes a query string and callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the results of a database query through exports.

in q.js

```
exports.query= function(string, callback) {
...
}
```

string is the sql query to get something from my database and callback is a function that takes to parameters: error, results.

in other js file

```
var string = "SELECT * FROM COLORS WHERE SHADE = ‘DARK’;";
var q = require('./q');
q.query(string, function(err, result) {

    console.log(result)

});
```

Currently, I am getting an error that says my string "SELECT * FROM COLORS WHERE SHADE = ‘DARK’;"; is an invalid or unexpected  token

Comment: I believe that you should use `'` instead of `‘` and `’` in your SQL query.

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript or imports/exports, but rather valid SQL syntax.